# How to join these two SELECT statements together to return a result?

Tags: sql

List the title of all books in the same category as books previously purchased by customer
1007. Don’t include books this customer has already purchased.(subqueries)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT title, customer#, category
FROM orders JOIN orderitems USING (order#)
        JOIN books USING (isbn)
WHERE isbn <> (SELECT customer#, isbn
        FROM orders o JOIN orderitems oi 
        ON o.order#=oi.order#
        where o.order#=oi.order# and o.customer#=1007);
```

The first select returns all book titles and the second select returns all books purchased by the same customer. I tried using `NOT IN ()` but get the same result as when using <>, =any,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change.

```
SELECT title, customer#, category
FROM orders JOIN orderitems USING (order#)
        JOIN books USING (isbn)
WHERE isbn NOT IN (SELECT isbn
        FROM orders o JOIN orderitems oi 
        ON o.order#=oi.order#
        where o.order#=oi.order# and o.customer#=1007);
```

I know you had already tried `NOT IN`, but the sub select should have only one column returning, in this case, the `isbn`.

Comment: Thanks that works and can't believe it was just that small change but usually it makes the difference doesn't it? Could I trouble you with  two other queries I have? If so I will post them later for you or someone else to respond. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anthony, there is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/) website, which helps you to build the schema and data on the fly, and helps you to work on it. :) Try it out and ping me the link too. Will check out and help you out. :)

Comment: Oh I see I will try that and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: When I run the above query it does not give the proper results. It is possible I have different table data. Which edition of the book are you using?

Comment: @The_Redhawk Do you understand that you're looking at an answer that was posted like 10 years ago? Should be from the previous century.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I do realize that. But when searching about this subject, this answer came up. I don't see a problem adding a comment about how in 2021 the above solution no longer works.

Comment: Additionally, if the OP is using the same set of tables I have, then the answer above does not account for the category restriction specified in the problem. But again, this is assuming we have the same data.

Comment: @The_Redhawk Appreciate your feedback and yes, once upon a time, a decade ago, this answer **worked** for the OP.  If you have a question, you can very well ask it again, if possible ask me to answer, I'll be more than happy to answer it. 

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT title, category 
FROM books WHERE category IN
 (SELECT category FROM books JOIN orderitems USING (isbn) 
   JOIN orders USING (order#) WHERE customer# = 1007)
 AND isbn NOT IN (SELECT isbn FROM orders JOIN orderitems USING (order#)
WHERE customer# = 1007);
```